# Random Error with Exit Code 1 - Xcode 6.1 Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, compiler-errors

I was running Xcode and had no issues. All of a sudden (after deleting my trash; don't know if that matters), I experienced this lovely problem.

> CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
>       cd /Users/OCedeno/Desktop/Showcase
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc
>   -target x86_64-apple-ios8.1 -module-name Showcase -Onone -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk
>   -g -module-cache-path /Users/OCedeno/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -I
>   /Users/OCedeno/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Showcase-cfyodwbqpzuutkgbhoyijshscdhu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F /Users/OCedeno/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Showcase-cfyodwbqpzuutkgbhoyijshscdhu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F /Users/OCedeno/Desktop/parse-library-1 -c -j4 /Users/OCedeno/Desktop/Showcase/Showcase/LoginVC.swift
>   /Users/OCedeno/Desktop/Showcase/Showcase/ResponsiveTextFieldViewController.swift
>   /Users/OCedeno/Desktop/Showcase/RegistrationVC.swift
>   /Users/OCedeno/Desktop/Showcase/Showcase/AppDelegate.swift
>   /Users/OCedeno/Desktop/Showcase/Showcase/DefinitionClass.swift
>   /Users/OCedeno/Desktop/Showcase/Showcase/MainPage.swift
>   /Users/OCedeno/Desktop/Showcase/Showcase/SettingsVC.swift
>   -output-file-map /Users/OCedeno/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Showcase-cfyodwbqpzuutkgbhoyijshscdhu/Build/Intermediates/Showcase.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Showcase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Showcase-OutputFileMap.json
>   -parseable-output -serialize-diagnostics -emit-dependencies -emit-module -emit-module-path /Users/OCedeno/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Showcase-cfyodwbqpzuutkgbhoyijshscdhu/Build/Intermediates/Showcase.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Showcase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Showcase.swiftmodule
>   -Xcc -I/Users/OCedeno/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Showcase-cfyodwbqpzuutkgbhoyijshscdhu/Build/Intermediates/Showcase.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Showcase.build/swift-overrides.hmap
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/OCedeno/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Showcase-cfyodwbqpzuutkgbhoyijshscdhu/Build/Intermediates/Showcase.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Showcase.build/Showcase-generated-files.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/OCedeno/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Showcase-cfyodwbqpzuutkgbhoyijshscdhu/Build/Intermediates/Showcase.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Showcase.build/Showcase-own-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/OCedeno/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Showcase-cfyodwbqpzuutkgbhoyijshscdhu/Build/Intermediates/Showcase.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Showcase.build/Showcase-all-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/OCedeno/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Showcase-cfyodwbqpzuutkgbhoyijshscdhu/Build/Intermediates/Showcase.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Showcase.build/Showcase-project-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/OCedeno/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Showcase-cfyodwbqpzuutkgbhoyijshscdhu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include
>   -Xcc -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
>   -Xcc -I/Users/OCedeno/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Showcase-cfyodwbqpzuutkgbhoyijshscdhu/Build/Intermediates/Showcase.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Showcase.build/DerivedSources/x86_64
>   -Xcc -I/Users/OCedeno/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Showcase-cfyodwbqpzuutkgbhoyijshscdhu/Build/Intermediates/Showcase.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Showcase.build/DerivedSources
>   -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -emit-objc-header -emit-objc-header-path /Users/OCedeno/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Showcase-cfyodwbqpzuutkgbhoyijshscdhu/Build/Intermediates/Showcase.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Showcase.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Showcase-Swift.h -import-objc-header /Users/OCedeno/Desktop/Showcase/Showcase-Bridging-Header.h
>
> Command
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc
>   failed with exit code 1

Comment: Also, when the project is cleaned, the error disappears but once I build it again, the error pops back up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try: quit Xcode, delete Xcode caches files and DerivedData Folder

[image]

[image]

[image]

using Option-Click

[image]

If it doesn't help you should delete and reinstall Xcode

Comment: Finder - click on the Go menu while holding the option key. It will show  up your user's Library which normally is hidden by default