# segmentation fault 11 ios swift 1.2

Tags: xcode, swift, segmentation-fault, xcode6.3

I am new to stackoverflow, but I want to ask about the compiler error I got when compiling a swift project with some ObjC libraries.

`

```
0  swift                    0x0000000100dbba18 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(__sFILE*) + 40
1  swift                    0x0000000100dbbef4 SignalHandler(int) + 452
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff9500ef1a _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff5f55b6e8 _sigtramp + 3394553832
4  swift                    0x00000001009b284c (anonymous namespace)::ObjCPrinter::print(swift::Type, llvm::Optional<swift::OptionalTypeKind>, llvm::StringRef) + 108
5  swift                    0x00000001009b6c9e std::__1::__function::__func<(anonymous namespace)::ModuleWriter::forwardDeclare(swift::EnumDecl const*)::'lambda'(), std::__1::allocator<(anonymous namespace)::ModuleWriter::forwardDeclare(swift::EnumDecl const*)::'lambda'()>, void ()>::operator()() + 238
6  swift                    0x00000001009b6afc (anonymous namespace)::ModuleWriter::forwardDeclare(swift::NominalTypeDecl const*, std::__1::function<void ()>) + 236
7  swift                    0x00000001009b6664 void llvm::function_ref<void ((anonymous namespace)::ReferencedTypeFinder&, swift::TypeDecl const*)>::callback_fn<(anonymous namespace)::ModuleWriter::forwardDeclareMemberTypes(swift::IteratorRange<swift::DeclIterator>)::'lambda'((anonymous namespace)::ReferencedTypeFinder&, swift::TypeDecl const*)>(long, (anonymous namespace)::ReferencedTypeFinder&, swift::TypeDecl const*) + 196
8  swift                    0x00000001009b689f swift::TypeVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::ReferencedTypeFinder, void>::visit(swift::Type) + 207
9  swift                    0x00000001009b690b swift::TypeVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::ReferencedTypeFinder, void>::visit(swift::Type) + 315
10 swift                    0x00000001009b696b swift::TypeVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::ReferencedTypeFinder, void>::visit(swift::Type) + 411
11 swift                    0x00000001009b02b8 (anonymous namespace)::ModuleWriter::forwardDeclareMemberTypes(swift::IteratorRange<swift::DeclIterator>) + 360
12 swift                    0x00000001009af26d swift::printAsObjC(llvm::raw_ostream&, swift::Module*, llvm::StringRef, swift::Accessibility) + 2957
13 swift                    0x00000001006a67ec printAsObjC(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, swift::Module*, llvm::StringRef, bool) + 332
14 swift                    0x00000001006a5016 frontend_main(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*) + 4998
15 swift                    0x00000001006a3ae6 main + 1814
16 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff927975c9 start + 1
17 libdyld.dylib            0x000000000000009e start + 1837533910
```

`

The project compiled and works fine on Xcode 6.2 and prior, but when I try to compile it on Xcode 6.3 and 6.3.1, I got Command failed due to signal : Segmentation fault 11. Can someone help me? Thanks before.

EDIT : Just for your info, I currently use two Xcode in one Mac, Xcode 6.2 and 6.3.1, because Xcode 6.3.x can't compile my project so I'm still using Xcode 6.2, while trying to fix for 6.3.x.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random Error with Exit Code 1 - XCODE 6.1 Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27219115/random-error-with-exit-code-1-xcode-6-1-swift)

Comment: Might help. Cleaning the cache seems to be one of the regular things you need as XCode user.

Comment: I have already deleted the folders specified in that answer, but the result is still the same. The error is different anyway, I got a Command failed due to signal Segmentation fault 11, on that question the error is command failed with exit code 1. @LeonardoSavioDabus